# Not being able to install Ubuntu in my laptop

Tags: system-installation

Context: I tried installing Ubuntu in my HP Aero 13 (Ryzen 5 processor 64bit, 16 GB ram, 2.3Ghz Radeon Graphics, with pre-loaded windows).
I created a bootable USB but the installation media would get stuck at start-up for some reason. I tried multiple times and waited for almost an hour (which should take a maximum of 30 seconds as per the specs). After that I tried the same with different versions of Ubuntu, but every single trial failed somehow. For the case of Ubuntu 20.04, it loaded and installed successfully, but the system lagged and strangely, it would boot up very quickly sometimes but sometimes it would get stuck while booting and the overall performance was way slower.
This is when I started looking for other ways to get Ubuntu running. I tried creating a persistent bootable USB (basically installed the OS in a USB Drive). There was the same issue with 22.04 and 20.04. This time I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 but I wasn’t able to edit partitions. When I tried installing ubuntu 16.04, the installation crashed.
I tried booting the installation media (Ubuntu 22.04) in my old laptop and it worked just fine without any issue. There shouldn’t be any compatibility issue as my laptop is fairly recent, and Ubuntu runs really well even in systems with lower specs.
I tried using Virtual Box, but I find using it inconvenient. I don’t want to dual boot my device as it may reduce the performance. Please help me out if anyone knows what I might be missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 16.04 is out of the question because out of support (and off.topic here) and does NOT support such hardware. Trying other then the newest Ubuntu is also not very smart. So, focus on 22.04. First update UEFI and SSDs' firmware if applicable. Then 1. make sure the ISO you're using isn't corrupt, 2. Use a proper tool to burn the ISO, 3. disable Fast Boot (just in case) and optionally disable Secure Boot, and, if still available, make sure to disable CSM/Legacy/"BIOS" support to assure you're booting in UEFI mode, 4. Use the "safe graphics" option if you must.

Comment: On point 2, use either balenaEtcher or Rufus. Unetbootin also works.

Comment: How does the system run if you just run the Live cd and do not install to the harddisk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Well, nothing actually worked I tried everything, lastly I made a dual boot using ubuntu 16 and windows 11, that worked, then I updated it to 20, again when I tried to update it further i.e. to 22 it did not work either. Now I am working with 20, but here my wifi drivers has not been installed, again tried everything but did not work